# Discord.py Musicbot Skip Command PermissionError

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, audio-player

So as my first "major" project after starting to program, I've decided to make a Discord Bot. The problem here is my "skip" command. Somehow it works but I can't understand how.

```
def play_next(ctx):
if len(songs_list) >= 2:
    print(songs_list,"before del")
    del songs_list[0]
    print(songs_list[0], "new song")

    
    try:
        if os.path.isfile("song.mp3"):
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        print("permissionerror")
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([songs_list[0]])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"), after=lambda e: play_next(ctx))
    voice.isplaying()
```

And the skip command:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def skip(ctx):
voice.stop()
voice.skip()
try:
  os.remove("song.mp3")
except:
  pass
play_next(ctx)
```

I know it isn't the best way of handling that, but I am just beginning to code and this is how I got it to work.
In the skip command, when I didn't use voice.skip() I would have gotten a PermissionError printed out in the console.

With it included, I instead get the message "VoiceClient" object has no attribute "skip", but everything works in order so far. Can someone explain why?
I mean if skip doesn't exist, then why does it work? And how does it bypass the PermissionError?

Comment: Which OS do you use? In which location stored your file? Is it user accesible directory?

Comment: Windows 10. The python file is in the same directory as the "song.mp3" and everything is accessible even without administrator. It seems to me as if the file is still in use.

Comment: Could it be that when you close main proccess the `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio` is still processing the file? You could check some python proccess in activity monitor

Comment: That seems to be the case indeed. I mean the code works...but I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm doing a Discord bot as a first project in python as well. I found that what causes this is that `voice.stop()` makes the audio stop, but when it stops the `after=lambda` callback starts. Then, if you call `playNext()`, it will cause an error because the `after=lambda` callback is already being played, thus the `voice.skip()` method throws an exception and `playNext()` is never invoked, since the `after=lambda` callback was invoked instead. At least in my case, so I hope it helps you :D

The permission error is caused because when the `after=lambda` callback starts, the bot is playing a song, and while doing it you try to use the `playNext()` function so it causes the error.

Try with:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def skip(ctx):
voice.pause()
play_next(ctx)
```

Also, I apologize if I made any mistake with my English (not my native language).